# C# call WinApi?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, interop

I am trying to call a WinAPI function `DeviceIoControl` in C# with code [`IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinIoCtl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_set_disk_attributes) and pass struct [`SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_set_disk_attributes). I am trying do it with this code:

```cs
const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;

const uint IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0007c0f4;
const ulong DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY = 0x0000000000000002;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
    IntPtr hDevice,
    uint dwIoControlCode,
    IntPtr lpInBuffer,
    uint nInBufferSize,
    IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
    uint nOutBufferSize,
    out uint lpBytesReturned,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped
);

struct SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public uint Version;
    public bool Persist;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] Reserved1;
    public ulong Attributes;
    public ulong AttributesMask;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public uint[] Reserved2;
};

private bool SetReadonly(IntPtr handle)
{
    var sda = new SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES();
    sda.AttributesMask = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;
    sda.Attributes = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;

    int nPtrQryBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(sda);
    sda.Version = (uint)nPtrQryBytes;

    IntPtr ptrQuery = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nPtrQryBytes);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(sda, ptrQuery, false);

    uint byteReturned;
    var res = DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES, ptrQuery, (uint)nPtrQryBytes, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

    var ex = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    return res;
}
```

I receive error "Parameter incorrect". What is the right way to call `DeviceIoControl` function passing structure [`SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_set_disk_attributes)?

Comment: Does the same happen when you declare `DeviceIoControl` as `(IntPtr hDevice,  uint dwIoControlCode, [In] ref SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES lpInBuffer, ...)` and just pass the struct?

Comment: yes "ref sda" give same result

Comment: You should probably also include values for the used constants in your question.

Comment: Ah, obviously `BOOLEAN Persist` is a [single byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types) (`typedef BYTE BOOLEAN;`), not four bytes like C#'s `bool` or WinAPI's `BOOL`. Use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)`.

Comment: it works thank you very much

Comment: Your struct declaration is missing a [`StructureLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute) attribute for marshaling. Set the `LayoutKind` parameter to `Sequential`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is [applied by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393943/when-should-i-explicitly-specify-a-structlayout#comment87714578_393964).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original definition of [`SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_set_disk_attributes):

```cpp
typedef struct _SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES {
  DWORD     Version;
  BOOLEAN   Persist;
  BYTE      Reserved1[3];
  DWORDLONG Attributes;
  DWORDLONG AttributesMask;
  DWORD     Reserved2[4];
} SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES, *PSET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES;
```

makes use of `BOOLEAN` data type, which is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#BOOLEAN) as a synonym of `unsigned char` (1 byte), as opposed to [`BOOL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#BOOL) that is a synonym of `int` (4 bytes).

C#'s `bool` is marshaled as `BOOL` by default.
You need to [force it into one byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_UnmanagedType_I1):

```cs
{
    ...
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool Persist;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally code to set disk readonly

```
const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x2;
const uint FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x80000000;
const uint FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000;

const uint IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0007c0f4;
const ulong DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY = 0x0000000000000002;

const uint IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES = 459072;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
   IntPtr hDevice,
   uint dwIoControlCode,
   IntPtr lpInBuffer,
   uint nInBufferSize,
   IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
   uint nOutBufferSize,
   out uint lpBytesReturned,
   IntPtr lpOverlapped
);

struct SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES
{
   public uint Version;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
   public bool Persist;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public byte[] Reserved1;
   public ulong Attributes;
   public ulong AttributesMask;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
   public uint[] Reserved2;
};

public IntPtr CreateHandle(string driveLetter)
{
   string filename = @"\\.\" + driveLetter[0] + ":";
   return CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, 0x3, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, IntPtr.Zero);
}

private void SetReadonly(IntPtr handle)
{
   var sda = new SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES();
   sda.Persist = true;
   sda.AttributesMask = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;
   sda.Attributes = DISK_ATTRIBUTE_READ_ONLY;
   sda.Reserved1 = new byte[3] { 0, 0, 0 };
   sda.Reserved2 = new uint[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

   int nPtrQryBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(sda);
   sda.Version = (uint)nPtrQryBytes;

   IntPtr ptrQuery = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nPtrQryBytes);
   Marshal.StructureToPtr(sda, ptrQuery, false);

   uint byteReturned;
   bool res = DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DISK_ATTRIBUTES, ptrQuery, (uint)nPtrQryBytes, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
   bool res2 = DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out byteReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

   var mess = new List<string>();
   mess.Add(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
   mess.Add(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);

   MessageBox.Show(string.Join(" ", mess));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SetReadonly(CreateHandle(textBox1.Text));
}
```